# Youtube iFrame context menu oddities

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, iframe, youtube

I'm using youtube iframe to embed videos on a site of mine. I'm using the iframe so that visitors to the site that don't have flash installed will see a html5 capable player.

Everything plays and runs as expected until you right click on the video and select and option like "copy embed HTML" and the video jumps off to the left of the iframe.

Upon inspecting the source, it seems like there is a div with class `.player-actions-container` that has a css rule of `left: 101%` if i remove this rule the player jumps back to its starting position.

demo
http://www.neilcremins.com/yt_test/

unclicked image
http://www.neilcremins.com/yt_test/unclicked.png

clicked image
http://www.neilcremins.com/yt_test/clicked.png

Comment: Do you have this problem in all browsers? I was unable to replicate this in Chrome.

Comment: Only happens with chrome (18.0.1025.162) and chromium (18.0.1025.142 (Developer Build 129054 Linux)), haven't had a chance to test it on any other platform other than Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Your concern over lack of Flash presence is at this time [unwarranted](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplatformruntimes/statistics.html).

Comment: It was requested by the users of the site I work on as there is a high percentage of mac users where flash runs terribly as is well known.

Comment: The least awful way would be to fetch the direct webm URI server-side and do object element failover.